# How does Visual Studio choose which iOS simulator to start?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, xcode9

I have Xcode 8.3.3 installed, and Visual Studio works with that for both compilation and simulation.

I installed Xcode 9.0.1, and want to test the app on the iPhone X to make sure that there aren't any display issues.

I don't want to compile with Xcode 9.0.1, I just want to use the simulator.

I don't see where in Visual Studio for Mac I choose the simulator to run.  How do I configure Visual Studio to start a specific simulator?

Comment: there should be a dropdown to select simulator/device next to the active project and active config dropdowns

Comment: @Jason The items in that list appear restricted to iPhone 7 and below, and iOS 10 and below.  None of the new phone models or iOS versions appear in that list.

Comment: You have to target/compile with xcode 9.0.1 to show those simulators in the device dropdown. You would specify this in the "Xcode path" in the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin directly calls into the `SimulatorKit.framework` in Xcode9 vs `CoreSimulator.framework` in Xcode8 in order to start `Simulator.app` within each respected Xcode bundle and make calls into it.

So basically what you are asking is not possible within the VS4M IDE, but from the cmd-line it is using Xcode tools.

You can use `simctl` (via `xcrun`) to run a particular sim device and install an `app` bundle into it.

Get a list of all the supported sims (you need the device id (GUID):

```
xcrun simctl list
```

Boot a sim:

```
xcrun simctl boot BDC5B693-9957-4034-BEFD-D3545F875DF6
```

Display the booted sim:

```
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app
```

Install an app bundle in the booted sim:

```
xcrun simctl install booted /user/sushi/code/gitlab/iPadProGenomeDNADashboard/iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/GenomeDNADashboard.app
```

Doing this enables you to install a VS4M/Xcode8-based app bundle into a iPhone 8/8s/X/... Xcode9-based simulator and test the UI. You, of course, can not debug it this way.

Comment: When I attempt to run using the iPhone X device ID it indicates that I need to download the runtime.  I can run the simulator from xcode 9, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.  If I start the simulator directly and then attempt to install the app bundle, it appears that `simctl` can't control it, `CoreSimulator detected Xcode.app relocation or CoreSimulatorService version change.` Do I need to update the xcode command line utilities (and if so will that change usage of 8.3.3) or is there some target I can change somewhere to point to the 9.0.1 version?

Comment: @AdamDavis Using `xcode-select` you can switch between the active Xcode installation (I have 4 Xcode versions on just this one VM that I switch back and forth)